# Appending Items to a List from a File

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I've been scouring this forum and I can't seem to find the answer. I've also tried several different methods to extract this information by tweaking my code, but to no avail :(

So, I am trying to extract lines from a file with a simple mouse click (user clicks a button) then I want the user to be able to click another button. But my program crashes every time they click the button. I assume it's cause the list is not populating because I don't have anything inside the parenthesis of the .append()? I've also tried running the debugger, but it also keeps crashing whenever I click the button.

Your guys' insight is appreciated.

```
 fname_button = Rectangle(Point(65,86.5), Point(79,82.5))
 fname_button.setFill("Darkgreen")
 fname_button.draw(win)
 Text(Point(72,84.5), "Import family file").draw(win)            

 Mouse = win.getMouse()
 if (Check_Mouse(float(Mouse.getX()),65, 79, float(Mouse.getY()), 86.5, 82.5)):
    infile = open("name_input.txt", "r")
    data = infile.read
    infile.seek(0)
    lines = infile.readlines()
    MasterList = []
    #Puts all data into the master list
    for line in lines:
        MasterList.append()
        win.getMouse()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `data = infile.read`? You probably wanted to *call* that function. You can then just set `MasterList = data.splitlines(True)` without having to seek and reread the file. What is the point of the `for line in lines` loop here? What are you trying to do with it? You are ignoring the mouse position you read each iteration.

Comment: try running application without data = infile.read
    infile.seek(0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an item to `list.append` otherwise you'll get a `TypeError`:

```
MasterList = []
#Puts all data into the master list
for line in lines:
    MasterList.append(line)
    win.getMouse()
```

Also you can change your code to:

```
with open("name_input.txt", "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()       #call the method by using ()
    infile.seek(0)
    MasterList = []
    for line in infile:
        MasterList.append(line)
        Mouse = win.getMouse()
        #do something with the returned value, instead of simply ignoring them.
```

If you're not doing anything with the returned value of `win.getMouse()` and it is not a function with some side-effect then you don't need that loop at all. Just do:

```
MasterList = infile.readlines()
```

Comment: At which point `MasterList = infile.readlines()` would suffice.. Why loop over the list, get the mouse position each time and append the line to a new list? Nothing is done with the mouse position here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But OP's calling a function after each append.

Comment: Yes, and is *ignoring* the return value. The same function was used earlier in the code with `Mouse = win.getMouse()`, so I expect that function to not have side-effects.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah! didn't see that, I thought `win.getMouse()` is a function with some side-effect. Solution updated.

Comment: So I am still getting crashes. Could it be something else in my program?

Comment: @Izento Looks like yes.